# getting undefined at the time of JSON calling

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting this JSON object from server.

```
{
    "bidderEliminationRuleValueId": 9,
    "preAuctionNoticeId": 21598,
    "auctionDetailId": 434136,
    "market": "MKT3",
    "bidderEliminationRuleId": 6,
    "ruleInputValueStr": "{\"noOfPredicates\":3,\"predicates\":[{\"elements\":[{\"label\":\"No of bidder participated in SB\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"\",\"type\":\"display\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"bidder\",\"pre\":false,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false}]},{\"elements\":[{\"label\":\"No of bidder participated in SB\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"\",\"type\":\"display\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"bidder\",\"pre\":false,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false}]},{\"elements\":[{\"label\":\"No of bidder participated in SB\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"\",\"type\":\"display\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"bidder\",\"pre\":false,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false}]}]}",
    "priority": 5,
    "status": "A",
    "createId": 20480,
    "createDate": "May 3, 2021 6:39:14 PM",
    "updateId": 0,
    "stage": 0
}
```

this is my js calling

```
function loadMarketRuleDetails(){
    var url = "/EPSWeb/sda/getBidderEliminationRuleDetailsAction.do?operation=MARKET_RULE_DETAILS&ruleId="+$('#ruleId').val()+"&auctionNoticeId="+$('#auctionNoticeId').val();
     marketRuleDetails = fetchGetJsonData(url, false);
     var html = "";
     alert(marketRuleDetails.length +"--"+marketRuleDetails[1].ruleInputValueStr.noOfPredicates );
     
     }
}
```

marketRuleDetails is a list that returns list of value.
marketRuleDetails[1].ruleInputValueStr.noOfPredicates this line of code giving me undefined.

Comment: I assume that the `fetchGetJsonData` function is asynchronious. It means it either returns the Promise object of takes and one argument as a callback function that will receive its response. You can add its code here or try to check how `fetchGetJsonData` works and read how to handle async functions in JS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have json string in `ruleInputValueStr`. Try to `JSON.parse` it first.

```js
const parsed = JSON.parse(marketRuleDetails[1].ruleInputValueStr);
alert(marketRuleDetails.length +"--"+parsed.noOfPredicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the value, before trying to use it.
It's currently a string, but needs to be converted to JSON.

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
let marketRuleDetails = [{},
  {
    "bidderEliminationRuleValueId": 9,
    "preAuctionNoticeId": 21598,
    "auctionDetailId": 434136,
    "market": "MKT3",
    "bidderEliminationRuleId": 6,
    "ruleInputValueStr": "{\"noOfPredicates\":3,\"predicates\":[{\"elements\":[{\"label\":\"No of bidder participated in SB\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"\",\"type\":\"display\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"bidder\",\"pre\":false,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false}]},{\"elements\":[{\"label\":\"No of bidder participated in SB\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"\",\"type\":\"display\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"bidder\",\"pre\":false,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false}]},{\"elements\":[{\"label\":\"No of bidder participated in SB\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"\",\"pre\":true,\"value\":\"\",\"type\":\"display\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false},{\"label\":\"bidder\",\"pre\":false,\"value\":\"0\",\"type\":\"number\",\"options\":[],\"classAttr\":\"\",\"visible\":true,\"readonly\":false}]}]}",
    "priority": 5,
    "status": "A",
    "createId": 20480,
    "createDate": "May 3, 2021 6:39:14 PM",
    "updateId": 0,
    "stage": 0
  }
];

marketRuleDetails[1].ruleInputValueStr = JSON.parse(marketRuleDetails[1].ruleInputValueStr);

alert(marketRuleDetails.length + "--" + marketRuleDetails[1].ruleInputValueStr.noOfPredicates);
```